# Выделение целой и дробных частей числа с выводом в textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал код в консольном приложении который отделяет целое число от дробной части. Подскажите как вывести результат в textbox.text на winforms?

```
   double i=28.8;
        double b=14.4;
        double num = 0.0;
        num = i + b;
        var p = Math.Truncate(num);
        var t = Math.Round(num % 1, 2);
        Console.Write("{0} and {1}", p, t);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод на winforms как правило происходит при каком-либо событии, будь-то нажатие на кнопку или изменение какого-нибудь свойства. Сначала подумайте для чего вам это.
Если просто при загрузке формы, то создайте событие Form.Load (Если у вас Visual studio, то щёлкаете в любое пустое место на вашей форме, справа снизу будут её свойства, там выбираете вкладку события и находите Load, 2 раза туда щёлкаете и событие создастся), и вставляете код приведённый ниже.
По аналогии можно сделать на любое событие, такое как нажатие кнопки и т.д.

```
 private void frmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double i = 28.8;
            double b = 14.4;
            double num = 0.0;
            num = i + b;
            var p = Math.Truncate(num);
            var t = Math.Round(num % 1, 2);
            textBox1.Text = $"{p} and {t}";
        }
```

Comment: Сделал вывод суммы значений i и b в textBox.text по нажатию кнопки. Все работает. Спасибо большое!